# C# vertical label in a Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Is it possible to display a label vertically in a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)?

Comment: Depending on your use case the existing controls may meet your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1088958/19308.

Answer (score 21):

Labels are easy, all you have to do is override the `Paint` event and draw the text vertically. Do note that GDI is optimised for Drawing text horizontally. If you rotate text (even if you rotate through multiples of 90 degrees) it will looks notably worse.

Perhaps the best thing to do is draw your text (or get a label to draw itself) onto a bitmap, then display the bitmap rotated.

Some C# code for drawing a Custom Control with vertical text. Note that ClearType text NEVER works if the text is not horizontal:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public partial class VerticalLabel : UserControl
{
    public VerticalLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void VerticalLabel_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateTexture();
    }

    private void GenerateTexture()
    {
        StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(this.Height, this.Width);
        Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        G.Clear(this.BackColor);

        SolidBrush brush_text = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        G.DrawString(this.Name, this.Font, brush_text, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), format);
        brush_text.Dispose();

        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);

        this.BackgroundImage = img;
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if the parent panel has `Autosize=True`? Will it expand to fit the label, or is it oblivious to our manual drawing?

Comment: InitializeComponent doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: A TextChanged event handler is missing.

Answer (score 20):

Create a class `myLabel` which can rotate it's Text on any angle specified by you.

You can use it by code or simply dragging from ToolBox

```
using System.Drawing;

class myLabel:System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
    public int RotateAngle { get; set; }  // to rotate your text
    public string NewText { get; set; }   // to draw text
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Brush b =new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);           
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(this.RotateAngle);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.NewText, this.Font,b , 0f, 0f);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Now this custom control is used into your form.

**You have to set below properties**

```
 1. mylbl.Text = "";             //which can be changed by NewText property
 2. mylbl.AutoSize = false;      // adjust according to your text
 3. mylbl.NewText = "Hello";     // whatever you want to display
 4. mylbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;  // color to display
 5. mylbl.RotateAngle = -90;     //angle to rotate
```

Answer (score 12):

I expanded on Javed Akram's answer to resize the widget automatically (I needed this feature). It works for both positive and negative angles, the way that Javed states:

```
 1. mylbl.Text = "";             // which can be changed by NewText property
 2. mylbl.AutoSize = false;      // adjust according to your text
 3. mylbl.NewText = "Hello";     // whatever you want to display
 4. mylbl.ForeColor = Color.Red; // color to display
 5. mylbl.RotateAngle = -90;     // angle to rotate
```

Here is the code:

```
public class RotatingLabel : System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
    private int m_RotateAngle = 0;
    private string m_NewText = string.Empty;

    public int RotateAngle { get { return m_RotateAngle; } set { m_RotateAngle = value; Invalidate(); } }
    public string NewText { get { return m_NewText; } set { m_NewText = value; Invalidate(); } }

    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Func<double, double> DegToRad = (angle) => Math.PI * angle / 180.0;

        Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
        SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(this.NewText, this.Font, this.Parent.Width);

        int normalAngle = ((RotateAngle % 360) + 360) % 360;
        double normaleRads = DegToRad(normalAngle);

        int hSinTheta = (int)Math.Ceiling((size.Height * Math.Sin(normaleRads)));
        int wCosTheta = (int)Math.Ceiling((size.Width * Math.Cos(normaleRads)));
        int wSinTheta = (int)Math.Ceiling((size.Width * Math.Sin(normaleRads)));
        int hCosTheta = (int)Math.Ceiling((size.Height * Math.Cos(normaleRads)));

        int rotatedWidth = Math.Abs(hSinTheta) + Math.Abs(wCosTheta);
        int rotatedHeight = Math.Abs(wSinTheta) + Math.Abs(hCosTheta);

        this.Width = rotatedWidth;
        this.Height = rotatedHeight;

        int numQuadrants = 
            (normalAngle >= 0 && normalAngle < 90) ? 1 :
            (normalAngle >= 90 && normalAngle < 180) ? 2 :
            (normalAngle >= 180 && normalAngle < 270) ? 3 :
            (normalAngle >= 270 && normalAngle < 360) ? 4 :
            0;

        int horizShift = 0;
        int vertShift = 0;

        if (numQuadrants == 1)
        {
            horizShift = Math.Abs(hSinTheta);
        }
        else if (numQuadrants == 2)
        {
            horizShift = rotatedWidth;
            vertShift = Math.Abs(hCosTheta);
        }
        else if (numQuadrants == 3)
        {
            horizShift = Math.Abs(wCosTheta);
            vertShift = rotatedHeight;
        }
        else if (numQuadrants == 4)
        {
            vertShift = Math.Abs(wSinTheta);
        }

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(horizShift, vertShift);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(this.RotateAngle);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.NewText, this.Font, b, 0f, 0f);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This kills VS2013 Pro's designer

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to simply do it without adding code or classes to your project!

When you create your label, simply add:

```
this.label1.text = "V\nE\nR\nT\nI\nC\nA\nL\n";
```

This worked for me!

Comment: While this should work, it is not a good way of doing it. If you dynamically set the `Text` you would have to use a method to inject a `\n` between each character. It also would have issues when it gets too long or the window gets resized.

Comment: One more remark: instead of using explicitly stated `\n`, is is better to use `Enviroment.NewLine`, but then it gets quite long. (Why doing the things right sometimes feel so awkward ?)

Answer (score 5):

You can rotate text instead of the label control in the `OnPaint` event or `Paint` method:

```
private void uc1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    string Name;
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawString(Name, new Font("Tahoma", 8), Brushes.Black, 0, 0,
    new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical));
}
```

Comment: Simple and best :-)

Answer (score 2):

2015 update on an old post. Since most of the other answers seem to heavily affect VS2013's designer in terms of usability, I'd suggest this solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19774/Extended-Vertical-Label-Control-in-C-NET

Comment: This one worked best for me - thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 2):

It absolutely works. I found it on net and little changed

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.ComponentModel;


public class VerticalLabel : System.Windows.Forms.Label
{

    private bool bFlip = true;

    public VerticalLabel()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        stringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;
        stringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;

        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);

        Matrix storedState = g.Transform;

        if (bFlip)
        {
            g.RotateTransform(180f);
            g.TranslateTransform(-ClientRectangle.Width,-ClientRectangle.Height);  
        }
        g.DrawString(
            this.Text,
            this.Font,
            textBrush,
            ClientRectangle,
            stringFormat);

        g.Transform = storedState;
    }

    [Description("When this parameter is true the VLabel flips at 180 degrees."),Category("Appearance")]
    public bool Flip180
    {
        get
        {
            return bFlip;
        }
        set
        {
            bFlip = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Used pieces from others

Jeremy

```
public partial class VerticalLabel_UserControl : UserControl
{
    private IComponentChangeService _changeService;
    private string strPropertyText = "Vertical Text";

    public VerticalLabel_UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public override string Text { get { return base.Text; } set { base.Text = value; this.Invalidate(); } }

    private void VerticalLabel_UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateTexture();
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }


    private void GenerateTexture()
    {
        StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
       // format.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(this.Height, this.Width);
        Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        G.Clear(this.BackColor);

        SolidBrush brush_text = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        G.DrawString(this.strPropertyText, this.Font, brush_text, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), format);

        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);

        this.BackgroundImage = img;

        brush_text.Dispose();
    }

    public override System.ComponentModel.ISite Site
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Site;
        }
        set
        {
            _changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
            if (_changeService != null)
                _changeService.ComponentChanged -= new ComponentChangedEventHandler(OnComponentChanged);
            base.Site = value;
            if (!DesignMode)
                return;
            _changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
            if (_changeService != null)
                _changeService.ComponentChanged += new ComponentChangedEventHandler(OnComponentChanged);
        }
    }

    private void OnComponentChanged(object sender, ComponentChangedEventArgs ce)
    {
        VerticalLabel_UserControl label = ce.Component as VerticalLabel_UserControl;
        if (label == null || !label.DesignMode)
            return;
        if (((IComponent)ce.Component).Site == null || ce.Member == null || ce.Member.Name != "Text")
            return;

        //Causes the default text to be updated
        string strName = this.Name.ToLower();
        string strText = this.Text.ToLower();
        if (strText.Contains(strName))
        {
            this.Text = "Vertical Text";
        }
        else
        {
            strPropertyText = this.Text;
        }

        //Prints the text vertically
        GenerateTexture();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just turned off the AutoSize property and resized the label vertically. I made the label wide enough for only one character. Then I changed TextAlign to center to make the alignment look better. This worked great for me.