# Is it possible to rotate a button control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

Is it possible to rotate a button or any control at a particular angle in WinForms? If so, how?

Comment: Please be more specific. You haven't mentioned your GUI toolkit/framework, and you haven't specified what you mean by 'rotate' (by 90° only? by any angle?)

Comment: rotate with any angle (90,180,...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can't rotate controls.** That's simply not supported by the native API controls that WinForms uses.

And one might wonder why it even *should* be supported. What could you possibly be trying to do that you'd need to rotate a button control? It would be much easier to draw it in a different place with a different shape in the first place, rather than trying to rotate an existing control. (Do note that you can also resize and reposition a control at run-time, if that would fit your needs. Investigate  the [`Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx) and [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) properties.)

The only workaround is to draw the control's image to a bitmap, hide the control, and draw the bitmap onto the form in the location you want it to appear. Of course, that won't result in a control that the user can *interact* with. They won't be able to click an *image* of a button, because it's not a real button. If that's acceptable to you, you should probably be using an image in the first place, rather than a button.

Answer (score 10):

If you **really** want to (I have no idea why one would..*) you could try to use a `Button` subclass, maybe like that:

```
public partial class TurnButton : Button
{
    public TurnButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int angle = 0;   // current rotation
    Point oMid;      // original center

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    {
        base.OnLayout(levent);
        if (oMid == Point.Empty) oMid = new Point(Left + Width / 2, Top + Height / 2);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
       int mx = this.Size.Width / 2;
       int my = this.Size.Height / 2;
       SizeF size = pe.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);
       string t_ = Text;
       Text = "";

        base.OnPaint(pe);

        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            Text = t_; pe.Graphics.TranslateTransform(mx, my);
            pe.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
            pe.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-mx, -my);

            pe.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText,
                                  mx - (int)size.Width / 2, my - (int)size.Height / 2);
        }
    }



    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(Height, Width);
        this.Location = new Point(oMid.X - Width / 2, oMid.Y - Height / 2);
        angle = (angle + 90) % 360;
        Text = angle + "°";

        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

(* I have no idea why I wrote that, either ;-)

Comment: I have no idea why I'm using this :)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the question asked here:
[Rotating a .NET panel in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864180/rotating-a-net-panel-in-winforms)

The quick summary of answers from that question is that while it may be possible to do it, it would be very, very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround in some cases would be this:

Use a tabControl , and resize it so you only have the button left. Set the allignment to left/right, and you have your button rotated 90/270 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

you may also make an exact same version of the button that you already have but make it invisible (visible.false) then rotate it when not in runtime and then while in runtime you can make it appear and make the unrotated version disappear so it looks like it has been rotated and it functions the exact same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
public class VerticalButton : Button
{
    public string VirticalText { get; set; }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
        SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);

        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        pe.Graphics.DrawString(VirticalText, this.Font, solidBrush,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), stringFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: code only answer is deprecated. you should add some explanation