# .NET Winforms Vertical Progress Bar Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wndproc, createparams

Recently, I needed a vertical progress bar for my win forms application. The derived class is like below. I also need to add text on progress bar. A label on it doesn't work beacuse of transperancy issues. After some research, I have found something. But the problem is, while progress bar is vertical, the text on it appears horizontal. I need it vertical too. How can I do that?

Thanks.

```
public class VProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x04;

            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
            {
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
            }

            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            {
                SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);
                graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, (Width - textSize.Width) / 2, (Height - textSize.Height) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Font;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Font = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the older answers on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371943/c-sharp-vertical-label-in-a-winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.aspx) to draw your string in vertical, using the flag. Try the following in your `WndProc` method:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            {
                StringFormat format = new StringFormat(
                       StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical);

                SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);
                graphics.DrawString(
                     Text, Font, brush, 
                     (Width / 2 - textSize.Height / 2),
                     (Height / 2 - textSize.Width / 2),
                     format);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it worked. I also needed to use graphics.RotateTransform(180) to show text bottom to top.