# How can I rotate text or a number 90° in Windows Forms/C++?

Tags: c++, winforms

I want to rotate a block of text or a number 90° in a Windows Forms application, Visual Studio 2010 (C++). Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[C# vertical label in a Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371943/c-sharp-vertical-label-in-a-windows-forms)*.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a [LOGFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and play with the values of **lfEscapement** and **lfOrientation**, like so:

```
SetGraphicsMode(hdc, GM_ADVANCED);

LOGFONT font          = {0};

font.lfHeight         = 0;
font.lfWidth          = 0;
font.lfEscapement     = 900; // here
font.lfOrientation    = 900; // and here
font.lfWeight         = 0;
font.lfItalic         = false;
font.lfUnderline      = false;
font.lfStrikeOut      = false;
font.lfCharSet        = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
font.lfOutPrecision   = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
font.lfClipPrecision  = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
font.lfQuality        = CLEARTYPE_QUALITY;
font.lfPitchAndFamily = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;

auto newfont = CreateFontIndirect(&font);
auto oldfont = SelectObject(hdc, newfont);

/* do actual drawing here */

SelectObject(hdc, oldfont);

SetGraphicsMode(hdc, GM_COMPATIBLE);

DeleteObject(newfont);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String theString = "90 Degree Rotated Text";
SizeF sz = e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Size;
//Offset the coordinate system so that point (0, 0) is at the center of the desired area.
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(sz.Width / 2, sz.Height / 2);

//Rotate the Graphics object.
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90);
sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(theString, this.Font);

//Offset the Drawstring method so that the center of the string matches the center.
e.Graphics.DrawString(theString, this.Font,
Brushes.Black, -(sz.Width/2), -(sz.Height/2));

//Reset the graphics object Transformations.
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
```

Copied from [here](http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/NET-Drawing-GDI/32846836/rotation-of-text.aspx)

Comment: OOPS, I noticed only the Winforms tag..
I this this should help.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/740/Simple-text-rotation

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your answer, where in which block i put the code? I tried it in this event    private: System::Void label37_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {}, it did not work. The windows forms do not understand e. Thank you very much!