# How to make textbox rotated 90 (vertical) during typing?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I need to make a vertical textbox like excel. A typing cursor shows as vertical and if I input some text , a text will be extended from top to bottom. And Text is rotated 90 degree.(Not spilt line)

[image]

How to create a vertical textbox in WinForm?

Comment: Not really possible. While you can owner-draw the text while you type, the user won't be able to do regular editing stuff like selection with a mouse and visualo feedback. Better fake it with a TextBox input field in your properties editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question got me curious! So I tried to implement something. And turns out it is kinda complicated to do in `winforms`…

Here is my shot, you will need to improve it, but it works(ish). The idea is to paint a white background to hide the text draw by the `TextBox`, then draw it vertically.

**Result:**

[image: TextBox with vertical text.]

Note that you can improve the result using another method to draw the text — [this code for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371959/5734097).

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class VerticalTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool bFlip = true;

    public VerticalTextBox() 
    {
        Multiline = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
    {
        Invalidate(); // repaint all
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), ClientRectangle);

        var stringFormat = new StringFormat {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            Trimming = StringTrimming.None,
            FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical
        };

        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);

        var storedState = g.Transform;

        if (bFlip)
        {
            g.RotateTransform(180f);
            g.TranslateTransform(-ClientRectangle.Width,-ClientRectangle.Height);  
        }
        g.DrawString(
            Text,
            Font,
            textBrush,
            ClientRectangle,
            stringFormat);

        g.Transform = storedState;
    }



    [Description("When this parameter is true the VLabel flips at 180 degrees."),Category("Appearance")]
    public bool Flip180
    {
        get => bFlip;
        set
        {
            bFlip = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**References**

1. [VerticalLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42116443/5734097)
2. [SetStyle](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?379960-Why-textbox-s-paint-event-ever-executes) to tell the TextBox to call the Paint event.

**BETTER(?) ALTERNATIVES**

1. To get better results, in winforms, I recommend you to learn about the [FastColoredTextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting-2) and use it.
2. Migrate to WPF, [apparently is easy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-apply-transforms-to-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).