# How to Rotate Label 90 Degrees in C#

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, label

I have a desktop application that projects names to the screen based on the numbers received from the card reader. However, the screen is sideways, so I want the names to appear on the screen rotated 90 degrees. How can I do it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "0013864285")

            {
                label1.Text = "Roy Randle";
                textBox1.Clear();

            }
            if (textBox1.Text == "0016657328")

            {
                label1.Text = "Jake Garrett";
                textBox1.Clear();

            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.TextChanged += this.textBox1_TextChanged;
        }
```

I made several attempts but no success.

Comment: `I made several attempts`. What attempts? Please [edit] and add what you have tried so far. Highlight exactly where you struggle.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to rotate a TextBox in WinForms by 90°. To show text that way you can only use a UserControl with self-made paint like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371943/c-sharp-vertical-label-in-a-windows-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to make textbox rotated 90 (vertical) during typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043811/how-to-make-textbox-rotated-90-vertical-during-typing)

Comment: If the physical screen is rotated, why not configure windows to rotate the entire desktop? Why deal with it in the application?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to display the text characters vertically:

```
    public string RotateText(string input)
    {
        var charArray=input.ToCharArray();
        return string.Join("\n", charArray);
    }

    // use this function 

     label1.Text = RotateText("Roy Randle");
```

Comment: This way the text is vertical but the letters don't turn sideways. I don't want the letters to be one after the other, but I want the text to be written sideways.