# How to output a rotated text in C# form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a c# form application and i want to draw a scale and write some rotated values under it,is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416897/how-do-i-rotate-a-label-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You will need to custom draw using the Graphics class. I assume you have some idea how to do that but if not that's a whole other question on its own involving OnPaint overrides and such. You can then use the Graphics class's [RotateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform) method and draw the text.

[A Bob Powell article about text rotation.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811074921/http://bobpowell.net/angletext.aspx)