# create moving text

Tags: c#, text

how can i make  a text moving from top to bottom to top....  (like a news window) in a textBox

Comment: Can you post an image to describe what you are looking for? I presume you are asking how to move text about in a c# winforms window?

Comment: Are you talking in a Windows application or an ASP.NET website?

Comment: its silverlight, not asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming windows forms)

I haven't tried to do this before, but my first attempt would include loading a bunch of text (like new headlines) into a textbox, and then making a timer that changes the vertical scroll value on the tick event? A textbox has built-in functions called ScrollToLine(), ScrollToVerticalOffset(), etc. Otherwise some controls, like panels have more direct access to scrollbar values. For example: SplitContainer.Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = value;

If those don't work, you can always draw the text yourself via graphics object and then update the positions items are drawn at.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to do it for web and if it is windows have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416897/how-do-i-rotate-a-label-in-c) . Hope it helps