# How to control the orientation of Drawstring?

Tags: c#, clr, gdi+

I want to draw a string as an axis label. When I draw the string with following code, I can read it "from the left". The base line of the text is at the left side.

```
StringFormat format = CustomGraphics.StringFormat(ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
e.Graphics.DrawString(this.yAxis.Title.Text, this.yAxis.Title.Font,
                      textBrush, e.Bounds, format);
format.FormatFlags &= ~StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
```

I want to draw vertical but turn the orientation by 180 degrees. How can I control this? Is there another method that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I rotate a label in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416897/how-do-i-rotate-a-label-in-c) contains a long and powerful paint method, based originally on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/customtext.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links to the samples. This gave me insight to the other methods, Hans mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Use Graphics.RotateTransform() to get the string rotated the way you want it.  You'll need TranslateTransform() and MeasureText() to get the start-point right.