# How to change DevExpress MVC Grid header text on export to vertical (from bottom to top)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I'm using DevExpress v14.1 to export the grid content as an image.

The whole functionality is working, I even got the header to show in vertical mode

```
settings.SettingsExport.RenderBrick += (s, e) => {
            if (e.RowType == GridViewRowType.Header)
            {
                e.BrickStyle.StringFormat = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BrickStringFormat( StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical | StringFormatFlags.NoClip | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
                return;
            }
            else if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data)
            {
                return;
            }
```

But I got the text starting at the top of the header and going to the bottom, and I want it the other way, going from the bottom to the top of the header.

[image: As in this example]

Comment: Have you check the properties for gridview . ApperancePrint-->HeaderPanel-->TextOption-->HAlignment to Far. Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry Its my bad, try instead of HAlignment with VAlignment to Bottom.

Comment: Thanks @Mdyahiya, but I don't have the gridview properties, I'm just using the MVC control, I have the DevExpress.Web.Mvc.GridViewSettings to work with.

Comment: Please check this, they are discussing about Horizontal Alignment. It should be same to vertical alignment. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q227686/gridview-how-to-set-a-header-text-alignment and this https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.AppearanceStyleBase.VerticalAlign.property

Comment: That didn't work, I tried that. This alignment is on top, bottom or middle.

Comment: Sorry I dont know any other properties. Just thought of changing orientation. Please check this it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369869/how-to-control-the-orientation-of-drawstring

Comment: I created an issue in the DevExpress support, after i'll create an answer https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T729145/how-to-change-devexpress-mvc-grid-header-text-on-export-to-vertical-from-bottom-to-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the DevExpress forum answer.

> Hello, 
>   As far as I understand you need to turn headers 180 degrees. I researched this scenario and found that RenderBrick does not provide the capability to do this. You can use our XtraReports suite that provides wide capabilities for export and allows the grid export. See the Create a Table Report documentation article. Let me know if you need any further assistance.
>
> As for your second question, the cell size is calculated earlier than RenderBrick is raised based on cell content. RenderBrick allows customizing the exported text style but without changing cell size. So, your workaround is appropriate in this case.

[That's the forum link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T729145/gridview-export-how-to-turn-headers-in-the-exported-pdf-file)