# Is there a way using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting to rotate a Candlestick chart to display horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: c#, data-visualization, mschart, candlestick-chart

I want the candles to be displayed left to right not bottom to top.  I cant seem to find anything with how to achieve this using this library.  Some other client side libraries can do this but I am confined to server side code using this library at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think to create a horizontal candlestick chart you need to rotate a normal candlestick chart and change the `Primary` and `Secondary` status of the axis. Rotating objects in `Forms` it not straightforward and something I haven't tried.

There is a lot of material on how to rotate simple objects such as labels on StackOverflow and you need to implement some code like the below examples to rotate your `mschart`

[C# vertical label in a Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371943/c-sharp-vertical-label-in-a-windows-forms)

[How do I rotate a label in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416897/how-do-i-rotate-a-label-in-c)

I think otherwise you may need to look to other charting sources such as [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/)

I'd be interested to know how you get on so if you find a solution if you could share it that would be great