# Unicode special character not displaying in label

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, console-application, unicode-string

I would like to print that kind of [character](http://unicode-table.com/en/#1F6B5), but I dont get it, I thought c# supports unicode.

The way I solved it:

```
label3.Text = "\u1F6B5";
```

This is not the only symbol ,which does not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  label3.Text = "\u1F6B5";
```

The `\u` escape takes only 4 hex digits, you are trying to use 5.  So you end up with a string that contains two characters, '\u1F6B' and '5'.  Looks like "Ὣ5", not what you want.

Using codepoints from the upper bit planes (codes >= 0x10000) require a capital U to get properly encoded into a string literal.  Fix:

```
  label3.Text = "\U0001F6B5";
```

The machine also needs a font that contains the glyph.  You'll know it is missing when you see a rectangle instead.

Comment: Can I flip unicode characters, for example that the biker drives the other direction or would this be the only soloution(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416897/how-do-i-rotate-a-label-in-c) to rotate the label ?

Comment: Awesome. This was driving me crazy that I couldn't get it to work either. Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today to struggle with. I found CompatibleTextRendering property has an affect if Unicode symbols are displayed or not.

See image [here](https://github.com/r-pankevicius/UnicodeInWinForms) how it affects Label and LinkLabel controls.

I solved it using Segoe UI Emoji font.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to select a font that supports the unicode character for your label. Try something like Arial Unicode MS (or take a look at [this guideline](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6b5/fontsupport.htm) for fonts supporting that exact unicode character... e.g. [the Segoe UI Symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/segoe_ui_symbol/index.htm) font).

Comment: To get things working, I have to buy that font http://www.fonts.com/de/font/monotype/arial-unicode/ms-regular for 189Euros(209$) ,because I can not select it in the designer (under "Font"->"Name") ? This is quite a lot .. for some testing. I could not select/find "Symbola font", so I tried "Symbol" -font and it does not work.

Comment: You should be able to set the font through code (and I believe through the designer is possible if the font is installed). I'm sure there are free fonts out there that support this unicode character, but I'm not positive... will research a bit more

Comment: Try this link: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%F0%9F%9A%B5+-+MOUNTAIN+BICYCLIST+%28U%2B1F6B5%29 It should tell you local fonts you have installed that support the unicode character.

Comment: Ok setting through the code like this("label3.Font = new Font("Symbola font", label3.Font.Size); label3.Font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", label3.Font.Size);"), does not work on my machine.By the way as default I have "Microsoft Sens Serive"(after commenting out the above mentioned code) selected , by looking at the list(http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%F0%9F%9A%B5+-+MOUNTAIN+BICYCLIST+%28U%2B1F6B5%29) ,it tells me I have to use "1F6B5", but this is what I had before and it did not work out ..

Comment: I tried downloading symbola and setting it through code shows a totally different character (the wrong one). Then if I try to set it through the designer it says it is not a true type font. Strange.