# Xamarin Forms FontIcon Upper Bitplane XAML Escape Character

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, glyphicons

I'm trying to use [MaterialDesignIcons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) in a Xamarin Forms Shell app. The latest version of this font encodes all of the glyphs in the upper bit planes (see this old [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690885/unicode-special-character-not-displaying-in-label) about that).

The problem I have is that I don't know how to identify the proper XAML escape sequence for upper bit plane glyphs. For example, `\uf30c` in C# code translates to `&#xf30c;` in XAML. But I don't know how to translate an upper bit plane value (e.g. `\U000f0706`) to the correct XAML escape sequence.

I thought I'd just use a binding to code instead, but this is blocked by [an open bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12700). There's a workaround in that GitHub issue, but it doesn't seem to work for a Tab Bar Icon (which is where I'm trying to use it).

TL;DR - how to I write `\U000f0706` in XAML?

Comment: If you only want to use it in Tab bar, you can download icons and use it directly as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT - I guess this is my only option for now